# Differentiable parameterization of a curve $\Gamma$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

If $\alpha:I\longrightarrow \Gamma$ and $\beta:J\longrightarrow \Gamma$ are two bijective differentiable regular parameterizations of the curve  $\Gamma\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ (not necessarily of class $C^1$) where $I,J\subset\mathbb{R}$(compact intervals).

Can we say that $\theta=\beta^{-1}\circ \alpha$ is differentiable ?

Note that $\alpha ,\beta,\theta$ are homeomorphisms.

Any hints would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How do you define a differentiable curve? A differentiable map from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Comment: Yes, as a limit.

Comment: WHat do you mean, as a limit?

Comment: If there is the limit $\displaystyle \alpha\,'(a)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\alpha(a+t)-\alpha(a)}{t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key fact that you need here is the fact that the inverse function theorem holds (under the mere differentiability assumption) for the maps of the Euclidean space. No continuity assumption for derivatives is needed in this theorem. See blog post by Terry Tao [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/).

Next, the problem you have is a purely local question. Thus, for every $t\in I$ you can find a neighborhood $I'$ and a local diffeomorphism (coordinate change) $F$ of the plane such that $F\circ \alpha(s)=(s,0)$, $s\in I'$. The proof of existence of such $F$ is a reduction to the inverse function theorem as explained for instance on page 15 (local immersion theorem) of the book by Guillemin and Pollack "Differential Topology". Now, the claim reduces to the case of maps between intervals of the real line, which is immediate.